# What is expected from a SlickGrid editor factory?

Tags: javascript, editor, factory, slickgrid

Should the return value of *SomeEditorFactory.getEditor(column)* be a function or an object?

From the code

```
function getEditor(row, cell) {
    var column = columns[cell];
    var rowMetadata = data.getItemMetadata && data.getItemMetadata(row);
    var columnMetadata = rowMetadata && rowMetadata.columns;

    if (columnMetadata && columnMetadata[column.id] && columnMetadata[column.id].editor !== undefined) {
        return columnMetadata[column.id].editor;
    }
    if (columnMetadata && columnMetadata[cell] && columnMetadata[cell].editor !== undefined) {
        return columnMetadata[cell].editor;
    }

    return column.editor || (options.editorFactory && options.editorFactory.getEditor(column));
}
```

Not immediately obvious.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When SlickGrid calls *YourEditorFactory.getEditor(column)*, it expects a function.

Comment: While technically correct (and you're free to accept your own answer here), this is misleading and unhelpful.

Comment: Misleading and unhelpful are rather vague descriptors in this case. If you would expand on that, I'd be more than happy to edit my answer. "It should be an object that implements getEditor(columnDefinition)" didn't really answer the question I was asking, so I chose to accept my own answer. IMHO, the API is misleading. I would assume that getEditor returned an object, not a function used to construct an object. My $0.02.

Comment: I asked this question in the first place, because the API design—IMHO—violates the principle of least surprise. "Get editor" to me implies a returning an object. "Get editor function" or "get editor constructor" are pretty self explanatory. My $0.02.

Answer (score 3):

It should be an object that implements `getEditor(columnDefinition)` and returns the editor for a given column.

See https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Writing-custom-cell-editors and https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.editors.js.

Comment: The return value of options.editorFactory.getEditor(column) should be a function.

Comment: I tried returning an object from editorFactory.getEditor(column) and I got an exception in Chrome.